# How to remove MySQL Workbench 5.2 in ubuntu unity?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-11.04, mysql-workbench

I have just download the .deb and installed it. It works. Now i want to uninstall it.

I have tried:

- sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench, but it says "E: Unable to locate package mysql-workbench".
- Go to the Software manager, but it's not between the installed apps.
- Execute again the .deb, but it doesn't give the option to uninstall it.

I reboot my pc after installing it.

Any idea?

Javier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very simple: If you have the .deb file in place run:

```
sudo dpkg -r workbench.deb
```

otherwise simply delete the installation directory of the workbench, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 13):

Follow link this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-linux-uninstalling.html

Uninstalling DEB packages

To uninstall a Debian package, use this command:

```
sudo dpkg -r mysql-workbench-community
```

This command does not remove the configuration files. If you wish to also remove the configuration files, use this command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge mysql-workbench-community
```

Answer (score 12):

The name of the MySQL Workbench package in Debian comes with the WB edition appended so it should be `mysql-workbench-gpl` for the GPL version and `mysql-workbench-se` for the SE version. You can search for the one you have installed with:

```
apt-cache search mysql-workbench
```

Once you have the proper package name you can remove it in the usual way:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench-gpl
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify the **edition** that you want to uninstall..

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench-community
```

Answer (score 4):

I removed using this command:

> sudo snap remove mysql-workbench-community

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the dependencies with the command below

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-*
```

Comment: This one is not advised. It will remove everything include MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. Go to Ubuntu Software Center
2. Click on installed Tab.
3. click Developer Tools
   You will get list of software.Select Workbench and remove it.